# Custom directive displays its own error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive that I would like to be in charge of displaying its own error and eventually handling its own validation. However it only seems to work if I put error-checking  outside of the directive. Does anyone know why that is?

```
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        title: 'Lorem Ipsum'
    };
})
.directive('customInput', function($compile){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: false,
      scope: { 
        title: '=',
        formName: '@'
      },
      template: '<div><input name="custom" required ng-model="title"/>' +
        '<span ng-show="{{formName}}.custom.$error.required">Required</span>' +
        '</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      }
    }
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N7NDb/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your solution is not working is that `{{formName}}` should not be in  double-curly braces, and the `formName: '@'` should be `formName: '='` . Looking deeper into why this is, but this solution should work.

Fork of [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6WmW/)

**Edit:**
The reason why @Edminsson and this solution work yield same results in this case:
**The reason this solution works:**
In the directive you are creating an isolated scope that has the propety 'formName' which will be set to the value of the attribute 'form-name'. The `formName: '='` creates a bi-directional binding to the property on the parent scope by the name that is defined by the attribute 'form-name'. So, this allows you direct access to the property on the parent scope (in this case 'Ctrl') and all of its available properties. This means that any changes that happen to the property on the parent scope will be reflected on the isolated scope. For this solution you **do not** need the curly braces because it is not an expression for Angular to evaluate, and you can reference all of the properties on the object that is being bound to.

**The reason @Edminsson solution works**
In the isolated scope instead of using `formName: '='` @Edminsson kept the original `formName: '@'` this meant that what was being placed in the property formName was a string from the attribute "form-name". That is what the '@' symbol returns, whatever the string representation is that is declared in the attribute. The next part that completes this solution is the usage of `ng-form = {{formName}}`, Angular recognizes this as an expression and replaces it with the value held inside of 'formName'. This in-turn creates a property on the parent scope with the name of what was held in 'formName'. This new property can be viewed as an "Angular Form", and thereby has all of the properties of an "Angular Form" (ie. pristine, dirty, valid). After this Angular evaluates the second instance of `{{formName}}`, so when it is finally written to the DOM and Angular evaluates the line
`<span ng-show="myForm.custom.$error.required">Required</span>` in-which "myForm" is a valid property on 'Ctrl' scope.

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) is the source that I pulled all my info.
With the vague requirements presented in the question both of these approaches solve the problem, but as things get more complex these solutions can be used in different ways.

I hope this helps and is not too convoluted or granular to be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FormController inside of directive templates does not behave the way one may expect. Using ng-form help in this kind of situation.

```
template: '<div ng-form="{{formName}}"><input name="custom" required ng-model="title"/>' +
    '<span ng-show="{{formName}}.custom.$error.required">Required</span>' +
    '</div>'
```

Fork of [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2SFD/)